# RxJS How to update when array (map) data changes?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a simple RxJS observable using `from` on a map:

When I set a new key/value to the map after subscribing to the observable, there are no `console.logs`. How do I get the observable to update when the data map changes so that the observers will console.log the change?

Am I missing something here? I've tried reading the docs and watching videos but havent found any data on how to achieve this. Thanks

```js
const data = new Map([['item1', value1], ['item2', 'value2'], ['item3', value3]]);
const data$ = Rx.Observable.from(data);
data$.subscribe(
    (x) => {
        console.log('OBSERVABLE X');
        console.log(x);
    },
    (err) => {
        console.log('OBSERVABLE ERR');
        console.log(err);
    },
    (complete) => {
        console.log('OBSERVABLE COMPLETE');
        console.log(complete);
    },
);
data.set('item3', 'value3');
```

Comment: Because you are not pusing the update from the observable to the subscriber. And it is not how observables operate

Comment: Are you saying that an Observable cant be setup to listen to changes on a Map for example and then push the changes to subscribers?

Comment: Observables are not actively watching the underlying sources for changes, if you change the underlying source,you have to tell the observable to broadcast the change to its subscribers, check out `Subject` and `BehaviorSubject` to do broadcasting. Just think about it, how would an observable know that you go behind its back and mutate the source ?

Answer (score 0):

your observable is cold, you need to make it hot to achieve the functionality you wish.

Hot observable are usually subjests, you need to convert this into subject and then try adding the another value in map and see, it should ideally then work.

```
  const subject = new Subject();
  data$.subscribe(subject)
```